# Can the release history of an app be retrieved with the Google Play Developer API?

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I am using the Google Play Developer API to retrieve info about the production track of an app (a.k.a., package).

I am performing the following requests in order:

1. `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, which successfully provides an access token.
2. `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits`, to initiate an *edit*.
3. `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits/{editId}/tracks/production`, to retrieve info about the production track of the app.

However, I only get info about the version currently in production:

```
{
    "track": "production",
    "releases": [
        {
            "name": "1.6.1",
            "versionCodes": [
                "230621566"
            ],
            "status": "completed"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the complete release history of the app?

I would expect something like the following:

```
{
    "track": "production",
    "releases": [
        {
            "name": "1.6.1",
            "versionCodes": [
                "230621566"
            ],
            "status": "completed"
        },
        {
            "name": "1.6.0",
            "versionCodes": [
                "230621560"
            ],
            "status": "completed"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a full release history from the API. Calling the *edits.tracks* resource in the Google Play Developers API returns only the **active** releases in the track ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks#Track)).